# Running at once multiple Subs from an unique VBA Sub

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine

I have three different Subs available in a VBA module and wanted to call those series of Subs from an unique Sub activated through a VBA button.

Below the code running:

```
Sub Updateworkbook()

Call Unprotectworkbook
Call CopyAndPaste
Call Protectworkbook

End Sub
```

After the first `Sub Unprotectworkbook()` is run the other `Sub` are not called and executed. Why this happens?

Below the `Unprotectworkbook()` Sub code for your reference

```
Sub Unprotectworkbook()

 Dim myCount
    Dim i
    myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(1).Select
    For i = 1 To myCount
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
        If i = myCount Then
            End
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: your code is correct. There could be something in `Unprotectworkbook` sub therefore you need to add code of it to your question. Are there any events in your workbook which would affect code execution?

Comment: Can you show code of `Unprotectworkbook` ?

Comment: it is hard to answer your question if we can't see the content of your `subs`. it's like looking for a needle in a haystack blindfolded.

Comment: using your logic, and without altering the code too much, just change `End` to `Exit For` or to `Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as follows (change `End` to `Exit Sub`):

```
Sub Unprotectworkbook()

 Dim myCount
    Dim i
    myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(1).Select
    For i = 1 To myCount
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
        If i = myCount Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

or you can simply change it to the next one:

```
Sub Unprotectworkbook()
    Dim sh   
    For Each sh In Sheets
       sh.Unprotect "password"
    Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to answer your question without seeing the code in all three subs.

Some pointers though:

1. You don't need to select each sheet in order to modify it - just use `Sheet(i).Unprotect "password"` in the for loop instead.
2. Also, since you have a for loop you don't need to code when it should end, if you have defined the `For i = 1 To myCount` statement correctly. In other words, remove the `If i = myCount Then End` part.
3. You could define the For loop like the following: `For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count` to simplify your code, then you can remove the `myCount` variable.
4. You should always define your variables with a datatype in order to minimize errors, e.g use `Dim i As Integer` instead.
5. *Always* use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module, also to minimize confusion and errors caused by typos etc.

I strongly advise you to run through a couple of tutorials on VBA, there are lots around. The following is just the first one up when searching, I haven't tried it: [Excel VBA Basic Tutorial 1](http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic1.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If this helps, I recommend making another set of 3 subs to test blank items first.  Otherwise use one of the other answers above.

```
Sub msgTEST0()    'Call msgTEST0
  Call msgTEST1
  Call msgTEST2
  Call msgTEST3
End Sub


Sub msgTEST1()
    MsgBox "MSG1" & Space(10), vbQuestion
End Sub

Sub msgTEST2()
    MsgBox "MSG2" & Space(10), vbQuestion
End Sub

Sub msgTEST3()
    MsgBox "MSG3" & Space(10), vbQuestion
End Sub
```